QGIS 3.34.5 LTR Virtual layers Crashes
Migrating from 3.28 to 3.34.5 I have a virtual layer that is causing crashes.
I am using a virtual layer to union 3 layers together to simplify the number of layers.
I have simplified the layer and it's symbology for testing.
This setup (with more complex symbology) works fine in 3.28 and allows me to do some very useful calculations on a single layer rather than 3.
In 3.345 the virtual layer works fine until I start editing the underlying data at which point QGIS crashes.
Here is the simplified query, is there an issue with the query that 3.45.5 picks but 3.28 doesn't or is something else going on?
select st_buffer(geometry, 5)
from Trees
where category in ('A','B','C','U')
UNION ALL
select st_buffer(geometry, 5)
from lines
where category in ('A','B','C','U')
UNION ALL
select st_buffer(geometry, 5)
from polygons
where category in ('A','B','C','U')


What is the error message?

@IanTurton - good point. No error message just a spinning blue circle, which isn't very informative.

As far as I can tell Virtual layers in 3.34.5 cause spikes in network traffic which crashes QGIS -  I suspect this will depend on the virtual layer source (geodatabase in this case so not ideal) and network configuration (windows server, again probably not the best).

network drives and writeable file databases never end well
